XD Mobile Preiview equivalent in Illustrator or any other Adobe product?
I am creating web banners in Illustrator. I know that XD had a preview option that you could download the XD App and view output on Mobile at real size. We don't in our company use XD anymore and am worndering if theres a workaround similar to XD in Adobe? The only thing I can think of is figma but we use Adobe files to share work so ideally an Adobe related solution.

Adobe has some mobile apps, but whether these are any use for your specific use case I don't know. Personally, I'd just use something else like Figma -see their solution
